# Mandatory verbalization of private information

Tags: united-states, banking, security, privacy

This year I am no longer able to access my account over my phone due the fact that my bank decided to drop (!!!) 2FA-class authorization, so verbalization of my personal information (!) is the only way I can access my account without an internet browser. Is there some legal or any other argument I can state to restore access to my account (US) over the phone?

Comment: For legal questions you could try law.stackexchange.com (but check their help first to see if this sort of question is on topic), or better yet, consult a lawyer.

Comment: Is this to regain access to the browser interface? or is this how you will have to do all transactions?

Comment: Have you considered to just switch to a different bank?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal question.

Comment: What do you mean by "verbalization"?  That you actually have to say certain things?  But I would think requiring that would violate the Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA), since some people are unable to speak.  Regardless, I personally would switch banks.

Comment: @jamesqf To authorize in the system you have to spell your SSN/PIN or secret word/etc. Meaning you have to expose this data if you not in a private space. And if you live in an apartment building like I used to in Brooklyn - acoustic isolation there would render regular phone call as public.

Comment: @glibdud Sorry I meant more like any official argument, not the actual legal process.

Comment: @charlie137: If it was me, I'd either change banks, or stick with using a browser.  But then, I find the browser interface much more convenient anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some legal argument I can state to restore access to my account (US)?

To give an answer,

i. No. Without even looking at it, there is **100.0000% certainty that the boilerplate adhesion contract you made when opening the account** allows them to change/add/remove any apps or access methods at will.

Given (i), you fair and square started using a bank which stated in advance the app could disappear at any time, so, that's that.

However,

ii. Could there be a disability issue?  i.e. customer is not able to access now due to a disability.  In that case

(a) they *will not* change the whole app for you (as that costs millions),

(b) they *will* bend over backwards doing whatever it takes to avoid legal trouble from a disabled-rights group

(c) yes, in the USA, there is a non-zero chance you could actually bring a lawsuit (ie, a contingency ambulance chaser will do that for you) using the disability-2F angle; and/or if not a lawsuit, pressure from the relevant disabled-rights group.

Do note that a-b-c are only theoretical comments based on (ii).

Comment: Makes sense. I thought since they had it before they at least had to notify on changes like this. But seems like theres no way to deal with it.

Comment: Consumer rights now!